# Error when deploying to heroku in a Rails API

Tags: ruby, heroku, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm pretty a starter in Ruby on Rails and i've been struggling on a deploy to Heroku. I have an error when I want to deploy my Rails Api to heroku. This app that I have serves as an API to a React front end application. So based on that, my Rails app dosen't has any views folder or a Assets file to precompile, I was told that I need to deploy my Rails Api in one Heroku app and my React in another heroku app. But when i want to deploy my Rails App I got the following error message:

```
remote:        Bundle completed (41.51s)
remote:        Cleaning up the bundler cache.
remote: -----> Installing node-v10.15.3-linux-x64
remote: -----> Detecting rake tasks
remote: 
remote:  !
remote:  !     Could not detect rake tasks
remote:  !     ensure you can run `$ bundle exec rake -P` against your app
remote:  !     and using the production group of your Gemfile.
remote:  !     rake aborted!
remote:  !     ArgumentError: :key is required
remote:  !     /tmp/build_0f11c72c29e3e9275e9d2167ac1b7a98/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/dwolla_v2-2.2.1/lib/dwolla_v2/client.rb:21:in `initialize'
remote:  !     /tmp/build_0f11c72c29e3e9275e9d2167ac1b7a98/config/initializers/dwolla.rb:5:in `new'
remote:  !     /tmp/build_0f11c72c29e3e9275e9d2167ac1b7a98/config/initializers/dwolla.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
remote:  !     /tmp/build_0f11c72c29e3e9275e9d2167ac1b7a98/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.4/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `load'
remote:  !     /tmp/build_0f11c72c29e3e9275e9d2167ac1b7a98/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.4/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `load'
remote:  !     /tmp/build_0f11c72c29e3e9275e9d2167ac1b7a98/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:285:in `block in load'
remote:  !     /tmp/build_0f11c72c29e3e9275e9d2167ac1b7a98/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:257:in `load_dependency'
remote:  !     /tmp/build_0f11c72c29e3e9275e9d2167ac1b7a98/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:285:in `load'
remote:  !     /tmp/build_0f11c72c29e3e9275e9d2167ac1b7a98/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/engine.rb:657:in `block in load_config_initializer'
remote:  !     /tmp/build_0f11c72c29e3e9275e9d2167ac1b7a98/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:170:in `instrument'
remote:  !     /tmp/build_0f11c72c29e3e9275e9d2167ac1b7a98/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/engine.rb:656:in `load_config_initializer'
remote:  !     /tmp/build_0f11c72c29e3e9275e9d2167ac1b7a98/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/engine.rb:614:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Engine>'
remote:  !     /tmp/build_0f11c72c29e3e9275e9d2167ac1b7a98/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/engine.rb:613:in `each'
remote:  !     /tmp/build_0f11c72c29e3e9275e9d2167ac1b7a98/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/engine.rb:613:in `block in <class:Engine>'
remote:  !     /tmp/build_0f11c72c29e3e9275e9d2167ac1b7a98/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:32:in `instance_exec'
remote:  !     /tmp/build_0f11c72c29e3e9275e9d2167ac1b7a98/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:32:in `run'
remote:  !     /tmp/build_0f11c72c29e3e9275e9d2167ac1b7a98/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:61:in `block in run_initializers'
remote:  !     /tmp/build_0f11c72c29e3e9275e9d2167ac1b7a98/vendor/ruby-2.5.3/lib/ruby/2.5.0/tsort.rb:228:in `block in tsort_each'
remote:  !     /tmp/build_0f11c72c29e3e9275e9d2167ac1b7a98/vendor/ruby-2.5.3/lib/ruby/2.5.0/tsort.rb:350:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component
remote:  !     /tmp/build_0f11c72c29e3e9275e9d2167ac1b7a98/vendor/ruby-2.5.3/lib/ruby/2.5.0/tsort.rb:422:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component_from'
remote:  !     /tmp/build_0f11c72c29e3e9275e9d2167ac1b7a98/vendor/ruby-2.5.3/lib/ruby/2.5.0/tsort.rb:431:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
remote:  !     /tmp/build_0f11c72c29e3e9275e9d2167ac1b7a98/vendor/ruby-2.5.3/lib/ruby/2.5.0/tsort.rb:421:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component_from'
remote:  !     /tmp/build_0f11c72c29e3e9275e9d2167ac1b7a98/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:50:in `each'
remote:  !     /tmp/build_0f11c72c29e3e9275e9d2167ac1b7a98/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:50:in `tsort_each_child'
remote:  !     /tmp/build_0f11c72c29e3e9275e9d2167ac1b7a98/vendor/ruby-2.5.3/lib/ruby/2.5.0/tsort.rb:415:in `call'
remote:  !     /tmp/build_0f11c72c29e3e9275e9d2167ac1b7a98/vendor/ruby-2.5.3/lib/ruby/2.5.0/tsort.rb:415:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
remote:  !     /tmp/build_0f11c72c29e3e9275e9d2167ac1b7a98/vendor/ruby-2.5.3/lib/ruby/2.5.0/tsort.rb:349:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component'
remote:  !     /tmp/build_0f11c72c29e3e9275e9d2167ac1b7a98/vendor/ruby-2.5.3/lib/ruby/2.5.0/tsort.rb:347:in `each'
remote:  !     /tmp/build_0f11c72c29e3e9275e9d2167ac1b7a98/vendor/ruby-2.5.3/lib/ruby/2.5.0/tsort.rb:347:in `call'
remote:  !     /tmp/build_0f11c72c29e3e9275e9d2167ac1b7a98/vendor/ruby-2.5.3/lib/ruby/2.5.0/tsort.rb:347:in `each_strongly_connected_component'
remote:  !     /tmp/build_0f11c72c29e3e9275e9d2167ac1b7a98/vendor/ruby-2.5.3/lib/ruby/2.5.0/tsort.rb:226:in `tsort_each'
remote:  !     /tmp/build_0f11c72c29e3e9275e9d2167ac1b7a98/vendor/ruby-2.5.3/lib/ruby/2.5.0/tsort.rb:205:in `tsort_each'
remote:  !     /tmp/build_0f11c72c29e3e9275e9d2167ac1b7a98/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:60:in `run_initializers'
remote:  !     /tmp/build_0f11c72c29e3e9275e9d2167ac1b7a98/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/application.rb:361:in `initialize!'
remote:  !     /tmp/build_0f11c72c29e3e9275e9d2167ac1b7a98/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
remote:  !     /tmp/build_0f11c72c29e3e9275e9d2167ac1b7a98/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.4/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `require'
remote:  !     /tmp/build_0f11c72c29e3e9275e9d2167ac1b7a98/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.4/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
remote:  !     /tmp/build_0f11c72c29e3e9275e9d2167ac1b7a98/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.4/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:92:in `register'
remote:  !     /tmp/build_0f11c72c29e3e9275e9d2167ac1b7a98/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.4/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:21:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
remote:  !     /tmp/build_0f11c72c29e3e9275e9d2167ac1b7a98/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.4/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:30:in `require'
remote:  !     /tmp/build_0f11c72c29e3e9275e9d2167ac1b7a98/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `block in require'
remote:  !     /tmp/build_0f11c72c29e3e9275e9d2167ac1b7a98/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:257:in `load_dependency'
remote:  !     /tmp/build_0f11c72c29e3e9275e9d2167ac1b7a98/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `require'
remote:  !     /tmp/build_0f11c72c29e3e9275e9d2167ac1b7a98/lib/tasks/dev_seed.rake:1:in `<top (required)>'
remote:  !     /tmp/build_0f11c72c29e3e9275e9d2167ac1b7a98/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.4/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `load'
remote:  !     /tmp/build_0f11c72c29e3e9275e9d2167ac1b7a98/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.4/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `load'
remote:  !     /tmp/build_0f11c72c29e3e9275e9d2167ac1b7a98/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:285:in `block in load'
remote:  !     /tmp/build_0f11c72c29e3e9275e9d2167ac1b7a98/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:257:in `load_dependency'
remote:  !     /tmp/build_0f11c72c29e3e9275e9d2167ac1b7a98/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:285:in `load'
remote:  !     /tmp/build_0f11c72c29e3e9275e9d2167ac1b7a98/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/engine.rb:650:in `block in run_tasks_blocks'
remote:  !     /tmp/build_0f11c72c29e3e9275e9d2167ac1b7a98/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/engine.rb:650:in `each'
remote:  !     /tmp/build_0f11c72c29e3e9275e9d2167ac1b7a98/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/engine.rb:650:in `run_tasks_blocks'
remote:  !     /tmp/build_0f11c72c29e3e9275e9d2167ac1b7a98/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/application.rb:515:in `run_tasks_blocks'
remote:  !     /tmp/build_0f11c72c29e3e9275e9d2167ac1b7a98/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/engine.rb:459:in `load_tasks'
remote:  !     /tmp/build_0f11c72c29e3e9275e9d2167ac1b7a98/Rakefile:6:in `<top (required)>'
remote:  !     /tmp/build_0f11c72c29e3e9275e9d2167ac1b7a98/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/rake-12.3.3/lib/rake/rake_module.rb:29:in `load'
remote:  !     /tmp/build_0f11c72c29e3e9275e9d2167ac1b7a98/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/rake-12.3.3/lib/rake/rake_module.rb:29:in `load_rakefile'
remote:  !     /tmp/build_0f11c72c29e3e9275e9d2167ac1b7a98/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/rake-12.3.3/lib/rake/application.rb:703:in `raw_load_rakefile'
remote:  !     /tmp/build_0f11c72c29e3e9275e9d2167ac1b7a98/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/rake-12.3.3/lib/rake/application.rb:104:in `block in load_rakefile'
remote:  !     /tmp/build_0f11c72c29e3e9275e9d2167ac1b7a98/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/rake-12.3.3/lib/rake/application.rb:186:in `standard_exception_handling'
remote:  !     /tmp/build_0f11c72c29e3e9275e9d2167ac1b7a98/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/rake-12.3.3/lib/rake/application.rb:103:in `load_rakefile'
remote:  !     /tmp/build_0f11c72c29e3e9275e9d2167ac1b7a98/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/rake-12.3.3/lib/rake/application.rb:82:in `block in run'
remote:  !     /tmp/build_0f11c72c29e3e9275e9d2167ac1b7a98/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/rake-12.3.3/lib/rake/application.rb:186:in `standard_exception_handling'
remote:  !     /tmp/build_0f11c72c29e3e9275e9d2167ac1b7a98/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/rake-12.3.3/lib/rake/application.rb:80:in `run'
remote:  !     /tmp/build_0f11c72c29e3e9275e9d2167ac1b7a98/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/rake-12.3.3/exe/rake:27:in `<top (required)>'
remote:  !     ./vendor/bundle/bin/rake:29:in `load'
remote:  !     ./vendor/bundle/bin/rake:29:in `<main>'
remote:  !
remote: /app/tmp/buildpacks/b7af5642714be4eddaa5f35e2b4c36176b839b4abcd9bfe57ee71c358d71152b4fd2cf925c5b6e6816adee359c4f0f966b663a7f8649b0729509d510091abc07/lib/language_pack/helpers/rake_runner.rb:106:in `load_rake_tasks!': Could not detect rake tasks (LanguagePack::Helpers::RakeRunner::CannotLoadRakefileError)
remote: ensure you can run `$ bundle exec rake -P` against your app
remote: and using the production group of your Gemfile.
remote: rake aborted!
remote: ArgumentError: :key is required
remote: /tmp/build_0f11c72c29e3e9275e9d2167ac1b7a98/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/dwolla_v2-2.2.1/lib/dwolla_v2/client.rb:21:in `initialize'
remote: /tmp/build_0f11c72c29e3e9275e9d2167ac1b7a98/config/initializers/dwolla.rb:5:in `new'
remote: /tmp/build_0f11c72c29e3e9275e9d2167ac1b7a98/config/initializers/dwolla.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
remote: /tmp/build_0f11c72c29e3e9275e9d2167ac1b7a98/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.4/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `load'
remote: /tmp/build_0f11c72c29e3e9275e9d2167ac1b7a98/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.4/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `load'
remote: /tmp/build_0f11c72c29e3e9275e9d2167ac1b7a98/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:285:in `block in load'
remote: /tmp/build_0f11c72c29e3e9275e9d2167ac1b7a98/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:257:in `load_dependency'
remote: /tmp/build_0f11c72c29e3e9275e9d2167ac1b7a98/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:285:in `load'
remote: /tmp/build_0f11c72c29e3e9275e9d2167ac1b7a98/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/engine.rb:657:in `block in load_config_initializer'
remote: /tmp/build_0f11c72c29e3e9275e9d2167ac1b7a98/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:170:in `instrument'
remote: /tmp/build_0f11c72c29e3e9275e9d2167ac1b7a98/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/engine.rb:656:in `load_config_initializer'
remote: /tmp/build_0f11c72c29e3e9275e9d2167ac1b7a98/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/engine.rb:614:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Engine>'
remote: /tmp/build_0f11c72c29e3e9275e9d2167ac1b7a98/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/engine.rb:613:in `each'
remote: /tmp/build_0f11c72c29e3e9275e9d2167ac1b7a98/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/engine.rb:613:in `block in <class:Engine>'
remote: /tmp/build_0f11c72c29e3e9275e9d2167ac1b7a98/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:32:in `instance_exec'
remote: /tmp/build_0f11c72c29e3e9275e9d2167ac1b7a98/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:32:in `run'
remote: /tmp/build_0f11c72c29e3e9275e9d2167ac1b7a98/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:61:in `block in run_initializers'
remote: /tmp/build_0f11c72c29e3e9275e9d2167ac1b7a98/vendor/ruby-2.5.3/lib/ruby/2.5.0/tsort.rb:228:in `block in tsort_each'
remote: /tmp/build_0f11c72c29e3e9275e9d2167ac1b7a98/vendor/ruby-2.5.3/lib/ruby/2.5.0/tsort.rb:350:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component'
remote: /tmp/build_0f11c72c29e3e9275e9d2167ac1b7a98/vendor/ruby-2.5.3/lib/ruby/2.5.0/tsort.rb:422:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component_from'
remote: /tmp/build_0f11c72c29e3e9275e9d2167ac1b7a98/vendor/ruby-2.5.3/lib/ruby/2.5.0/tsort.rb:431:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
remote: /tmp/build_0f11c72c29e3e9275e9d2167ac1b7a98/vendor/ruby-2.5.3/lib/ruby/2.5.0/tsort.rb:421:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component_from'
remote: /tmp/build_0f11c72c29e3e9275e9d2167ac1b7a98/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:50:in `each'
remote: /tmp/build_0f11c72c29e3e9275e9d2167ac1b7a98/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:50:in `tsort_each_child'
remote: /tmp/build_0f11c72c29e3e9275e9d2167ac1b7a98/vendor/ruby-2.5.3/lib/ruby/2.5.0/tsort.rb:415:in `call'
remote: /tmp/build_0f11c72c29e3e9275e9d2167ac1b7a98/vendor/ruby-2.5.3/lib/ruby/2.5.0/tsort.rb:415:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
remote: /tmp/build_0f11c72c29e3e9275e9d2167ac1b7a98/vendor/ruby-2.5.3/lib/ruby/2.5.0/tsort.rb:349:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component'
remote: /tmp/build_0f11c72c29e3e9275e9d2167ac1b7a98/vendor/ruby-2.5.3/lib/ruby/2.5.0/tsort.rb:347:in `each'
remote: /tmp/build_0f11c72c29e3e9275e9d2167ac1b7a98/vendor/ruby-2.5.3/lib/ruby/2.5.0/tsort.rb:347:in `call'
remote: /tmp/build_0f11c72c29e3e9275e9d2167ac1b7a98/vendor/ruby-2.5.3/lib/ruby/2.5.0/tsort.rb:347:in `each_strongly_connected_component'
remote: /tmp/build_0f11c72c29e3e9275e9d2167ac1b7a98/vendor/ruby-2.5.3/lib/ruby/2.5.0/tsort.rb:226:in `tsort_each'
remote: /tmp/build_0f11c72c29e3e9275e9d2167ac1b7a98/vendor/ruby-2.5.3/lib/ruby/2.5.0/tsort.rb:205:in `tsort_each'
remote: /tmp/build_0f11c72c29e3e9275e9d2167ac1b7a98/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:60:in `run_initializers'
remote: /tmp/build_0f11c72c29e3e9275e9d2167ac1b7a98/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/application.rb:361:in `initialize!'
remote: /tmp/build_0f11c72c29e3e9275e9d2167ac1b7a98/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
remote: /tmp/build_0f11c72c29e3e9275e9d2167ac1b7a98/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.4/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `require'
remote: /tmp/build_0f11c72c29e3e9275e9d2167ac1b7a98/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.4/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
remote: /tmp/build_0f11c72c29e3e9275e9d2167ac1b7a98/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.4/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:92:in `register'
remote: /tmp/build_0f11c72c29e3e9275e9d2167ac1b7a98/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.4/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:21:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
remote: /tmp/build_0f11c72c29e3e9275e9d2167ac1b7a98/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.4/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:30:in `require'
remote: /tmp/build_0f11c72c29e3e9275e9d2167ac1b7a98/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `block in require'
remote: /tmp/build_0f11c72c29e3e9275e9d2167ac1b7a98/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:257:in `load_dependency'
remote: /tmp/build_0f11c72c29e3e9275e9d2167ac1b7a98/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `require'
remote: /tmp/build_0f11c72c29e3e9275e9d2167ac1b7a98/lib/tasks/dev_seed.rake:1:in `<top (required)>'
remote: /tmp/build_0f11c72c29e3e9275e9d2167ac1b7a98/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.4/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `load'
remote: /tmp/build_0f11c72c29e3e9275e9d2167ac1b7a98/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.4/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `load'
remote: /tmp/build_0f11c72c29e3e9275e9d2167ac1b7a98/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:285:in `block in load'
remote: /tmp/build_0f11c72c29e3e9275e9d2167ac1b7a98/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:257:in `load_dependency'
remote: /tmp/build_0f11c72c29e3e9275e9d2167ac1b7a98/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:285:in `load'
remote: /tmp/build_0f11c72c29e3e9275e9d2167ac1b7a98/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/engine.rb:650:in `block in run_tasks_blocks'
remote: /tmp/build_0f11c72c29e3e9275e9d2167ac1b7a98/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/engine.rb:650:in `each'
remote: /tmp/build_0f11c72c29e3e9275e9d2167ac1b7a98/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/engine.rb:650:in `run_tasks_blocks'
remote: /tmp/build_0f11c72c29e3e9275e9d2167ac1b7a98/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/application.rb:515:in `run_tasks_blocks'
remote: /tmp/build_0f11c72c29e3e9275e9d2167ac1b7a98/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/engine.rb:459:in `load_tasks'
remote: /tmp/build_0f11c72c29e3e9275e9d2167ac1b7a98/Rakefile:6:in `<top (required)>'
remote: /tmp/build_0f11c72c29e3e9275e9d2167ac1b7a98/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/rake-12.3.3/lib/rake/rake_module.rb:29:in `load'
remote: /tmp/build_0f11c72c29e3e9275e9d2167ac1b7a98/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/rake-12.3.3/lib/rake/rake_module.rb:29:in `load_rakefile'
remote: /tmp/build_0f11c72c29e3e9275e9d2167ac1b7a98/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/rake-12.3.3/lib/rake/application.rb:703:in `raw_load_rakefile'
remote: /tmp/build_0f11c72c29e3e9275e9d2167ac1b7a98/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/rake-12.3.3/lib/rake/application.rb:104:in `block in load_rakefile'
remote: /tmp/build_0f11c72c29e3e9275e9d2167ac1b7a98/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/rake-12.3.3/lib/rake/application.rb:186:in `standard_exception_handling'
remote: /tmp/build_0f11c72c29e3e9275e9d2167ac1b7a98/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/rake-12.3.3/lib/rake/application.rb:103:in `load_rakefile'
remote: /tmp/build_0f11c72c29e3e9275e9d2167ac1b7a98/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/rake-12.3.3/lib/rake/application.rb:82:in `block in run'
remote: /tmp/build_0f11c72c29e3e9275e9d2167ac1b7a98/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/rake-12.3.3/lib/rake/application.rb:186:in `standard_exception_handling'
remote: /tmp/build_0f11c72c29e3e9275e9d2167ac1b7a98/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/rake-12.3.3/lib/rake/application.rb:80:in `run'
remote: /tmp/build_0f11c72c29e3e9275e9d2167ac1b7a98/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/rake-12.3.3/exe/rake:27:in `<top (required)>'
remote: ./vendor/bundle/bin/rake:29:in `load'
remote: ./vendor/bundle/bin/rake:29:in `<main>'
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby app.
remote: 
remote:  !     Push failed
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote: 
remote: !       Push rejected to loop-stage.
remote: 
To https://git.heroku.com/loop-stage.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/loop-stage.git'
```

NOTE: This is an inherit project from a Client so the architecture was already like this.

Any idea on what could go wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the parameter `:key`(an alias of `:id`) is not passed to `DwollaV2::Client.new` properly.

[dwolla-v2-ruby-v2.2.1/lib/dwolla_v2/client.rb:21](https://github.com/Dwolla/dwolla-v2-ruby/blob/215343f5fb43ad0ce98a51e32bbae295a2c552ba/lib/dwolla_v2/client.rb#L21)

If you use environment variables to instantiate the `DwollaV2::Client` in `config/initializers/dwolla.rb`, are those environment variables configured in heroku correctly?

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars#managing-config-vars

You can check current variable values as follows:

```sh
$ heroku config:get YOUR_ENV_VAR_NAME
```

Comment: Junpei! Let me try this out and if works (which I think it will) I'll mark this a the best question!